# Missing some <keys> Your app has one or more issues, app rejected

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, info.plist

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyAPP". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

**Missing Info.plist key** - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSContactsUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

**Missing Info.plist key** - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

**Missing Info.plist key** - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

**Missing Info.plist key** - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

**Missing Info.plist key** - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an `NSSiriUsageDescription` key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.   
Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Why these key are asking even i am not using these features in my app.
Thank you.

Comment: What is your app about?

Comment: @User511
Thank you, 
My app is Educational app, where i am not using any Contacs, Music etc..

Comment: What is the category and detail of your app that you have mentioned in app store?

Comment: @User511 Thank you,
As i have seen i am not using any specific feature but this release containing support for 64-bit OS. and having push notif integration.
Category: Education Bussiness.
Compatability: iPhone, iPads.